# Implementing the LIST command correctly in an FTP server

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ftp, ftp-server

I'm trying to build a simple FTP server using Qt, but when I connect to it and type 'ls' using the Linux command line ftp client, I get the directory listing, but then there's a warning at the end:

```
WARNING! 30 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode
```

What does this warning mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I suspect that this message means that instead of file listings (a text line followed by CRLF per each file) your code sends a bunch of CRLF consequently. The parser doesn't understand this, as it expects text lines which describe files, not empty lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html):

> ```
> End-of-Line
>
>   The end-of-line sequence defines the separation of printing
>   lines.  The sequence is Carriage Return, followed by Line Feed.
> ```

All text you send using FTP should have newlines as `"\r\n"`, which obviously you don't have. You have to modify the text you send to the client, making sure it has correct line endings.

Comment: This will also apply when you implement ASCII mode for data connections as well. Although a little bit more complicated as when STORing a file, the data written to disk should have the platform standard line-endings (\n on UNIX, \r\n on Windows), while RETR should all be \r\n regardless of what platform the server runs on.